# Is anybody familiar with ServersAlive?

Tags: windows, monitoring

We used this at my last company and I thought it was a great product, so much so that I bought it at my current company.

However, there is one thing I can't figure out. At my last job, the program was always open. There was no way to close the program even if you wanted to (you might have been able to kill it via Task Manager, never tried that).

Is anybody familiar with this program that can help me out? I realize might be a bit obscure, but since sys admins use it, I figured it was worth checking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the question\problem? Do you want it to always run or do you not want it to always run?

Comment: I want it to always run.

At my last company we had it always running as a service but it appears to natively run as a process. I guess I need to look into how to change it to running as a service.

Comment: I figured it out.

It creates a service that you have to set to automatic, and then to be able to see the program you must login to the console.

Thanks for everybody's help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It creates a service that you have to set to automatic, and then to be able to see the program you must login to the console. Thanks for everybody's help.

Answer (score 0):

I used servers alive a couple of years ago - the only way we could make sure it was running 24/7 was to start it up on the console (as oppose to a remote session) and then lock the screen rather then log the user out.

From memory, the program never ran as a service so if you started it in a session, then closed that session - bye bye monitoring.

If you are having problems running it 24/7, try running it on the machine like that and see if that gets you anywhere.

Hope it helped.